# Add and Return Value From Function With Json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have function that uses ajax and json to get some values from table review. My json works. It gives value that I need. Now, I wanna to add every value I got inside `tr` and `td` and return it. But it gives '' or blank value. I hope there is solution for this :)

```
function get_review(id_jurnal){
var row= '';
var Example = (function () {
    function self() { } 
    self.Request = function (params) {
        $.ajax({
            data: "idjurnal_review="+id_jurnal,
            url:  "php/ambildata.php",
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            success: function ($json) {
                params.success($json);
            }
        });
  };
    return self;
})($);

var locale = Example.Request({
    async: true, // Set to false to enable synchronized calls
    url: "php/ambildata.php",
    success: function ($json) {
        locale = $json;

        var response = eval("(" + $json + ")");
        for(i=0;i < response.messages.pesan.length; i++) {
        id_review = response.messages.pesan[i].id_review;
        tglmulai_review = response.messages.pesan[i].tglmulai_review;
        tglselesai_review = response.messages.pesan[i].tglselesai_review;
        file_review = response.messages.pesan[i].file_review;

        var data = '<tr>'+
            '<td width="20%">Tgl Penunjukan</td>'+
            '<td width="1%">:</td>'+
            '<td>'+tglmulai_review+'</td>'+
        '</tr>';

        row = row + data;
        }
    }
});

return row; 
};

var id_jurnal = 1;
get_review(id_jurnal);
return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="redshown">'+get_review(id_jurnal)+'</table>';
```

Comment: Would you mind to show whats the json response like from the ajax? And I don't think it is necessary for you to use eval in order to iterate through your json object.

Comment: It show me data example: tglmulai_review, I get 25-06-2015

Comment: whats the point of calling `get_review(id_jurnal)` twice consecutively??

Comment: Ah, don't mind that. It's my mistake call twice. :D

Answer (score 0):

I got solution after refreshing my brain :D
This is What I do.
Firstly I make table first.

function format ( d ) {

```
return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="redshown"><tr id="tabelbaru"></tr></table>'; }
```

and after that i make function to calling data by ajax json

```
function get_review(id_jurnal){
var Example = (function () {
    function self() { } 
    self.Request = function (params) {
        $.ajax({
            data: "idjurnal_review="+id_jurnal,
            url:  "php/ambildata.php",
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            success: function ($json) {
                params.success($json);
            }
        });
  };
    return self;
})($);

var locale = Example.Request({
    async: true, // Set to false to enable synchronized calls
    url: "php/ambildata.php",
    success: function ($json) {
        locale = $json;

        var response = eval("(" + $json + ")");
        for(i=0;i < response.messages.pesan.length; i++) {
        id_review = response.messages.pesan[i].id_review;
        tglmulai_review = response.messages.pesan[i].tglmulai_review;
        tglselesai_review = response.messages.pesan[i].tglselesai_review;
        file_review = response.messages.pesan[i].file_review;
        idjurnal_review = response.messages.pesan[i].idjurnal_review;

        var row = $(document.createElement('tr')).attr("id", 'DivTambah' + idjurnal_review);
        row = '<tr>'+
            '<td width="20%">Tgl Penunjukan</td>'+
            '<td width="1%">:</td>'+
            '<td>'+tglmulai_review+'</td>'+
        '</tr>';
        $(row).insertBefore("#tabelbaru");
        }
    }

}); };
```

And use javascript to insert tr and td.
Thanks everyone :)